# Replace dmraid raind1 disk in CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, dmraid

Replaced a bad /dev/hdb, and try to rebuild the raid1, but something wrong like:

```
dmraid -dddvvv -R isw_chgadgfjjg_raid1 /dev/sdb
WARN: locking /var/lock/dmraid/.lock
WARN: missing dm serial file for /dev/dm-0
WARN: missing dm serial file for /dev/dm-1
WARN: missing dm serial file for /dev/dm-2
WARN: missing dm serial file for /dev/dm-3
WARN: missing dm serial file for /dev/dm-4
WARN: missing dm serial file for /dev/dm-5
WARN: missing dm serial file for /dev/dm-6
WARN: missing dm serial file for /dev/dm-7
WARN: missing dm serial file for /dev/dm-8
WARN: missing dm serial file for /dev/dm-9
NOTICE: /dev/dm-9: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-9: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-9: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-9: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-9: isw     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-9: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-9: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-9: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-9: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-9: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-9: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-8: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-8: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-8: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-8: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-8: isw     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-8: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-8: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-8: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-8: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-8: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-8: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-7: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-7: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-7: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-7: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-7: isw     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-7: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-7: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-7: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-7: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-7: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-7: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-6: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-6: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-6: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-6: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-6: isw     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-6: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-6: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-6: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-6: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-6: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-6: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-5: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-5: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-5: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-5: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-5: isw     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-5: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-5: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-5: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-5: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-5: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-5: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-4: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-4: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-4: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-4: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-4: isw     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-4: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-4: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-4: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-4: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-4: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-4: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-3: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-3: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-3: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-3: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-3: isw     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-3: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-3: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-3: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-3: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-3: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-3: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-2: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-2: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-2: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-2: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-2: isw     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-2: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-2: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-2: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-2: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-2: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-2: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-1: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-1: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-1: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-1: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-1: isw     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-1: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-1: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-1: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-1: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-1: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-1: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-0: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-0: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-0: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-0: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-0: isw     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-0: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-0: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-0: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-0: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-0: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/dm-0: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: isw     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: isw metadata discovered
NOTICE: /dev/sda: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: isw     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: via     discovering
DEBUG: _find_set: searching /dev/sdb
DEBUG: _find_set: not found /dev/sdb
DEBUG: _find_set: searching isw_chgadgfjjg
DEBUG: _find_set: not found isw_chgadgfjjg
DEBUG: _find_set: searching isw_chgadgfjjg_raid1
DEBUG: _find_set: searching isw_chgadgfjjg_raid1
DEBUG: _find_set: not found isw_chgadgfjjg_raid1
DEBUG: _find_set: not found isw_chgadgfjjg_raid1
NOTICE: added /dev/sda to RAID set "isw_chgadgfjjg"
NOTICE: dropping unwanted RAID set "isw_chgadgfjjg_raid1"
DEBUG: freeing devices of RAID set "isw_chgadgfjjg_raid1"
DEBUG: freeing device "isw_chgadgfjjg_raid1", path "/dev/sda"
DEBUG: freeing devices of RAID set "isw_chgadgfjjg"
DEBUG: freeing device "isw_chgadgfjjg", path "/dev/sda"
ERROR: either the required RAID set not found or more options required
no raid sets and with names: "/dev/sdb"
WARN: unlocking /var/lock/dmraid/.lock
```

googled it and have no luck, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is local access to the machine possible? Since this looks like a "fakeraid" configuration imported via dmraid, you might need to utilise the BIOS tools of the machine to condition the new disk and add it...